# spss: export cox regression survival function plot points

Tags: plot, spss, cox-regression

I want to export the plot points of a cox regression survival plot so i can use it in Graphpad Prism to make a nice graph out of it.

Question

1. How can i export the plot points?
2. is there maybe an easier way to export such a graph to edit it in graphpad?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should add a `save` subcommand to your analysis syntax:

```
/SAVE=SURVIVAL
```

After running the analysis you will find new column(s) containing the survival data which you can then export and plot elsewhere.

If you look in the Menu for the analysis you can see a button called  - click it to see all options of new variables to save, maybe you can find other data useful.

Comment: That works but i only get 1 line. Is it possible to get the seperate lines for the covariate (var)?

Comment: Sorry, I just don't konw :(   take a look [here](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/spss-statistics/23.0.0?topic=analysis-cox-regression-save-new-variables) maybe you'll find a hint. Or maybe wait a little longer for another answer to come up.